Any naming limitations for Journey Builder ampscript variables? I'm getting an unrecognized expression error
Error message says
Variable value expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
Script: set @TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT = [TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT]
Variable Name: @TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT
An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.
Script Expression: [TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT]
I have tested the email without issue. I have even done an actual send to myself and the email comes through. Field name is correct. There are no null values. Field is set to number and is being used as such. Could there be something about the variable name that Journey Builder doesn't like? Does the field in the sending data extension need to be renamed?
set @TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT = [TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT]

So I found out that the "TOTAL_VISIT_FOR_LIFETIME_CNT" was added to the sending data extension after the journey had already been running. That is why the field wasn't recognized. If you are adding a new field to the data extension, you have to create a new version of the journey.
